# Eyefinity PCI Express card with Apple Thunderbolt Display

Tags: thunderbolt, displayport, cinema-display, gpu

Can I connect the Apple Thunderbolt display to any PCI Express graphics card with Mini DisplayPort v1.2 Eyefinity technology?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a graphics card that can output Thunderbolt (if such things exist, I have not checked). The Apple Thunderbolt Display can *only* accept input in the form of a Thunderbolt signal, Mini DisplayPort will not work.

Apple does [sell a Mini DisplayPort variant](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC007LL/A) of their 27" display, so if you don't yet have the display you should get that instead

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Unfortuantely, the answer is no.

Comment: @CajunLuke The "M" in "Mini DisplayPort" is capitalized http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort

Comment: Well, damn. I'd swear I saw it lowercased consistently awhile ago. I must have been thinking of the Mac mini and iPod mini where it most certainly isn't. Now I have to go back and re-fix all the questions I "fixed". :)

Comment: There's a small note on the Thunderbolt product page: Customers with Macs that only support Mini DisplayPort output, such as the Mac Pro and MacBook, as well as previous generations of MacBook Pro, MacBook Air, Mac mini, and iMac can use the 27-inch LED Cinema Display.

Comment: I've read on the apple page that it should be backward compatible, are you SURE on that?

Comment: @HerrKaleun The backward compatibility only goes one way - you can use a Mini DP monitor with a TB Mac. Using a TB monitor with a Mini DP Mac doesn't work. If you don't have TB, you need to get the Mini DP monitor instead.

Comment: @kylecronin So getting a monitor with Mini DP but WITHOUT thunderbird (basically getting one older generation 27 inch) would do the trick, right?

Comment: @HerrKaleun Correct

Comment: @kylecronin thank you and btw, congratulations on the iPad :)

Comment: @HerrKaleun If you're referring to the contest, it's still not certain I've won one. They only have 5 to give out for level 3, and there are 9 people in it. But thanks anyway - I hope I do win!